# How i sorted this list?

Tags: python, parsing

How i can sort this by id?

```
lst = [
("Statistic", [{"name": "warehouse", "id":6}]),
("Instruction", [{"name": "Menu","id":2}]),
("Questions", [{"name": "How letter","id":3}])
]
```

I'm trying it
`sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[1])` But it don't work for me

> p.s i expect it:

```
[
("Instruction", [{"name": "Menu","id":2}]),
("Questions", [{"name": "How letter","id":3}]),
("Statistic", [{"name": "warehouse", "id":6}])
]
```

Comment: What's your expected output? What if `("Statistic", [{"name": "warehouse", "id":6}]` has multiple items in a list?

Answer (score 1):

`sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[1][0]['id'])` this work for me, thanks)